# Как добавить фреймворк в проект Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Раньше я писал обычные консольные приложения и не добавлял сторонние библиотеки и фреймворки в проекты. Теперь мне понадобилось добавить файл drogon.h из фреймворка [Drogon](https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon) командой #include <drogon/drogon.h>

Я не совсем понимаю, как нужно линковать и добавлять файлы этого репозитория в свойствах проекта Visual Studio. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать.

Comment: Проще всего поставить из vcpkg.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли.